# Change date format M/d/yyy hh:mm:ss to yyyy-MM-dd using expression

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

Hi I have one doubt in ssis

I want change date format `M/d/yyy hh:mm:ss` to  `yyyy-MM-dd` using ssis expression and DateFormat variable datatype is string  and  getting  format `like 5/28/2019 12:00:00 AM`. Data comes like below:

> 5/28/2019 12:00:00 AM

Based on above values i want output in other variable

> 2019-05-28

I tried like expression

```
(DT_STR, 4, 1252) DATEPART("yy" , @[User::DateFormat])  + "-" + 
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("mm" , @[User::DateFormat]), 2)  + 
"-" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("dd" , @[User::DateFormat]), 2)
```

but getting error like below :

> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> The function "YEAR" does not support the data type "DT_WSTR" for
>   parameter number 1. The type of the parameter could not be implicitly
>   cast into a compatible type for the function. To perform this
>   operation, the operand needs to be explicitly cast with a cast
>   operator.
>
> Evaluating function "YEAR" failed with error code 0xC0047089.
>
> The function "YEAR" does not support the data type "DT_WSTR" for
>   parameter number 1. The type of the parameter could not be implicitly
>   cast into a compatible type for the function. To perform this
>   operation, the operand needs to be explicitly cast with a cast
>   operator.

can you please tell me how to write expression to achive this task in ssis

Comment: Asking more than 25 questions without accepting any answer!! Please read the [Tour page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) to read more about upvoting and accepting answers

Answer (score 2):

The main error is that `@[User::DateFormat]` variable is a string variable while `DATEPART()` function can be only applied to a date time value. *(Even if the string variable stores a date time value)*

You can benefit from `TOKEN()` function to achieve that:

```
TOKEN(TOKEN( @[User::DateFormat],"/",3)," ",1) + "-" + 
RIGHT("0" + TOKEN( @[User::DateFormat],"/",2),2) + "-" + 
RIGHT("0" + TOKEN( @[User::DateFormat],"/",1) ,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added type casts for date.
This would help

```
(DT_WSTR, 4) YEAR( (DT_DATE) @[User::Variable]  ) + "-" + RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)  MONTH( (DT_DATE) @[User::Variable]  ),2) + "-" +  RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR, 2) DAY( (DT_DATE) @[User::Variable]  ),2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a new variable in your SSIS package with data type String and use the datetime field(here as `@[User::Variable]`) coming in your input in that variable as in below expression:

```
(DT_WSTR, 4) YEAR( @[User::Variable]  ) + "-" + 
RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)  MONTH( @[User::Variable]  ),2) + "-" +  
RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR, 2) DAY( @[User::Variable]  ),2)
```

You can convert this string variable into date type later on if required.

Comment: The OP mentioned that **DateFormat variable datatype is string**, how he can use `YEAR()` function?!

Comment: You can then use Date type cast for that. Just a bit of change                                        (DT_WSTR, 4) YEAR( (DT_DATE) @[User::Variable]  ) + "-" + RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)  MONTH( (DT_DATE) @[User::Variable]  ),2) + "-" +  RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR, 2) DAY( (DT_DATE) @[User::Variable]  ),2)

Comment: This is not the right way, even if it gives the expected output. Why converting to date then to string while you can use TOKEN() to simply extract these parts?

Comment: Agreed. Didn't knew about token before.

Comment: Check `TOKEN()` and `TOKENCOUNT()` functions, they are very useful: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3510/using-token-and-tokencount-in-sql-server-integration-services/